# Referencing the value of a variable in a jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace `$('#divy a:lt(3)')` and add the variable instead of number `$('#divy a:lt(count)')`, but it's not working.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neobian/9sUcx/1/)**

```
var timerId,
count = 0;

function end_counter() {
    $('#divy a:lt(3)').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('target', '_blank');
        $this.get(0).click(function () {
            window.open(this);
            return false;
        });
    });
    count = 0;
}
$('button').click(function () {

    count++;
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(end_counter, 700);
});
```

Comment: What is your overall goal? What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code? Telling us that you want to replace `$('#divy a:lt(3)')` doesn't help, as we don't know your ultimate goal.

Comment: `get(0)` returns a `DOM` object, not a `jQuery` object, but also, since `$this` is the subject of an `.each`, no reason to use `get` since `$this` is only a single element anyway.

Comment: When the 3 is there it will open up the first 3 hrefs in the div, by adding in a variable name instead of the number I want to change the number of hrefs that are open, eg: count= 5, open the first 5 pages. But when a add the variable name rather than the number it doesnt work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your jQuery selector is the string `$("#divy a:lt(count)")`. What you need to do is change that string depending on the content of count. Changing that to `$("#divy a:lt("+count+")")` should fix it for you. That way if count is 5 your selector is `$("#divy a:lt(5)")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have something like this to work

```
$('#divy a:lt('+count+')')
```